# how to create a contract which saves string for respective id and get details from array in for the respective id from react js?

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, ganache, react

I have created a contract like this, and I want to save data to array under respective Id and I want to fetch that data by entering that Id, like we:

Id: 73, Answer: your name

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

contract MyContract {
    struct Student {
        string Answers;
    }
    mapping(uint256 => Student) public students;
    Student[] public student;

    function getStudentMarks(uint256 _id) public view returns (string memory Answers, 
    address sender )
    {
        Student storage s = students[_id];
        return ( s.Answers, msg.sender);
    }

    function addMarks(uint256 Id, string memory Ans) public {
        Student = students[Id];
        Student.Answers = Ans;
        student.push(Id) -1;        
    }     
}
```

but I am getting these errors:

[image]

and how can I call these functions from reactjs, can someone help me, to make it work and I am using truffle, ganache and react js, but these errors are from remix IDE because I am trying to make it work on remix first and then move to my local project.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function:

```
function addMarks(uint256 Id, string memory Ans) public {
        Student = students[Id];
        Student.Answers = Ans;
        student.push(Id) -1;        
    }
```

You are creating a variable `Student` and assigning it a value of type `Student`. This cannot be done and solidity is confused. The variable cannot have the same name as a type, so change that variable name to `student`.
Also it would be a good practise to make `Answers` in your `Student` struct lowercase too.

Also your line `student.push(Id) - 1;` doesn't make much sense. `array.push()` returns a new length of the array and you are substracting 1 from it, but never saving that to any variable, so you can safely delete that substraction.

Edit:
Also upon taking a closer look at your code, I would rewrite is as follows, because having a mapping and an array is unnecessary in your case

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

contract MyContract {

    struct Student {
        string answers;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Student) public students;

    function getStudentMarks(uint256 _id) public view returns (string memory Answers, 
    address sender )
    {
        return ( students[_id].answers, msg.sender);
    }

    function addMarks(uint256 _id, string memory _ans) public {
        Student memory student = students[_id];  
        student.answers = _ans;
        students[_id] = student;
    }      
}
```

Edit2: To query a list of student marks, you could do:

```
    function getStudentsMarks(uint256[] memory _ids) public view returns (string[] memory answers, address _sender) {
        string[] memory answers = new string[](_ids.length);
        for (uint256 i; i < _ids.length; i++) {
            answers[i] = students[i].answers;
        }

        return (answers, msg.sender);
    }
```

Edit 4: This is probably something you need, needed to make it little bit more complex to retain the ability to edit existing users and assing whatever id you need.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Students {

    struct Student {
        string answers;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Student) public students;
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public mappingIdToStudentId;
    uint256 public numberOfStudents;

    function getStudentMarks(uint256 _id) public view returns (string memory Answers, 
    address sender )
    {
        return ( students[_id].answers, msg.sender);
    }

    function getStudentsMarks() public view returns (uint256[] memory ids, string[] memory answers, address _sender) {
        uint256[] memory ids = new uint256[](numberOfStudents);
        string[] memory answers = new string[](numberOfStudents);
        for (uint256 i; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
            ids[i] = mappingIdToStudentId[i];
            answers[i] = students[mappingIdToStudentId[i]].answers;
        }

        return (ids, answers, msg.sender);
    }

    function addMarks(uint256 _id, string memory _ans) public {
        require(bytes(_ans).length > 0, "Cannot save empty answer");

        Student memory student = students[_id]; 
        if(bytes(student.answers).length == 0) {
            mappingIdToStudentId[numberOfStudents] = _id;
            numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents + 1;
        } 

        student.answers = _ans;
        students[_id] = student;
    }     
}
```

Comment: Svediroh Thanks, it worked, but I need one more function to get all the entries in one go like Id = 73 and answers = "you name"; Id = 74 and answers = "my name"...., how can I achieve that.

Comment: when I use this method I got nothing in return, what should I put for "_ids" to get all students marks

Comment: Oh you need ALL of them. The function I did was to get only a selected list of ids

Comment: I want all the students marks, and when I pass array like this [71,72] to get the value of these ids it returns no value just this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl2JP.png

Comment: Sorry to bother you... but with this code I am getting no answers at all. below is the image link of what I am getting:

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ5F6.png